# C# Deserialize an object which is derived and has references

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a object of Type Node.
[Node.cs](https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/blob/master/src/WPFSamples/Samples/HousePlan/Node.cs)

The serialization works when I make the call as following:

```
var nodeSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mynode, Formatting.Indented,
   new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

My problem is that the following call does not work.

```
var n = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(nodeSer,
                new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
```

The call causes the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "ISerializable type 'System.Action' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present. Path 'Size.ValueChanged', line 35, position 5."
```

How do I have to design the the deserialization call?

Comment: Without a [mcve] I can't be sure, but maybe you want [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)?

Comment: @dbc Thanks, but it did not fix my problem. But I have extended the description. Do you have another idea?

Comment: In that case can you [edit] your question to include a full [mcve]?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You're essentially asking us to spend time recreating your problem in order to reproduce it, so we can then help you solve it.  That being said it looks like you are trying to serialize a delegate of type `Action<T>`, which is generally not implemented (and doesn't really make sense).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the hint. Node is derived from a class that is derived from _PropertyChangedBase_. This is the problem right?

Comment: For the future, whenever asking a question on stackoverflow about an exception, please include the full `ToString()` output of your exception, including message, traceback, and inner exception (if any).  When asking about JSON deserialization, please include a sample of the JSON you were trying to deserialize that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.NET does not serialize events so the `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged` in the [`PropertyChangedBase`](https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/blob/master/src/WPFSamples/Samples/HousePlan/PropertyChangedBase.cs) base type of the [`HousePlan`](https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/tree/master/src/WPFSamples/Samples/HousePlan) repository should not cause problems during (de)serialization.

However, at least one of the types in that repository has a `System.Action` delegate rather than an event to handle when a value changes, specifically   [`BindablePoint`](https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/blob/master/src/WPFSamples/Samples/HousePlan/BindablePoint.cs):

```
public class BindablePoint: PropertyChangedBase
{
    public double X
    {
        get { return Value.X; }
        set { Value = new Point(value,  Value.Y); }
    }

    public double  Y
    {
        get { return Value.Y; }
        set { Value = new Point( Value.X, value); }
    }

    private Point _value;
    public Point Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");

            if (ValueChanged != null)
                ValueChanged();
        }
    }

    // This property is causing problems for Json.NET
    public Action ValueChanged;
}
```

It's not clear why a delegate rather than an event is used for this purpose, however `System.Action` cannot be deserialized by Json.NET.  Indeed, serializing and deserializing these delegates makes no sense since they are assigned in the constructor for [`Node`](https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/blob/master/src/WPFSamples/Samples/HousePlan/Node.cs):

```
public class Node: DiagramObject
{
    public Node()
    {
        Size.ValueChanged = RecalculateSnaps;
        Location.ValueChanged = RecalculateSnaps;
    }
```

One simple solution is to mark these properties with [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm)

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Action ValueChanged;
```

A second simple solution would be to replace the delegate with a proper event, which Json.NET will now ignore:

```
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
```

If for whatever reason you cannot change these types, you can create a [custom `ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) that automatically ignores all delegate type properties:

```
public class IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<T> : IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    static IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<T> instance;

    static IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver() { instance = new IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<T>(); }

    public static IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<T> Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver() : base(new[] { typeof(T) }) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contract resolver to ignore properties of any number of given types.
/// </summary>
public class IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly HashSet<Type> toIgnore;

    public IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver(IEnumerable<Type> toIgnore)
    {
        if (toIgnore == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.toIgnore = new HashSet<Type>(toIgnore);
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.PropertyType.BaseTypesAndSelf().Any(t => toIgnore.Contains(t)))
        {
            property.Ignored = true;
        }

        return property;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

Now serialize with the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<System.Delegate>.Instance,
};
```

The `ValueChanged` property will no longer be serialized or deserialized.