# How to avoid recursive exporting of certain objects with Newtonsoft.Json on LinqPad

Tags: c#, json, json.net, linqpad

LinqPad connects to a SQL Server database.  The database has a table called ParentGroup. It also refers to many other tables in a complex graph.

There are hundreds of ParentGroups.

I want to export a single one of them and all the objects with it via Newtonsoft.JSon.

It works, except ParentGroup refers to several tables with many to many relationships that point back to the ParentGroup table.

So it actually serializes ALL of the ParentGroup objects when I serialize only one of them.

How can I prevent this?  One suggestion is to use JsonIgnore annotation but how to use that in LinqPad since Linqpad creates objects directly from database tables. So there isn't anywhere to set such annotations, is there?

Comment: You could use `IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<ParentGroup>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602946/3744182) to ignore all properties that refer to a `ParentGroup`.

Comment: Actually I discovered that these references back to ParentGroup a purely generated by LinqPad. They're not in the code. And they're not in the SQL database. LinqPad must do that for convencience to navigate.

Comment: How can I disable that in LinqPad?