# dotnet core 2: Serializing delegates is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I am trying to pass the scope (or `this`) to my custom exception and show it gracefully. My code was working until I added the scope property to the custom exception. I see others have encountered this issue ([link1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23415), [link2](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/issues/286), [link3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1404)) but no solution. Any solution or workaround would be appreciated. Thank you.

My custom exception:

```
  public class CustomException : Exception
  {
    private readonly object _scope;

    public CustomException(string message, object scope = null) : base(message)
    {
      _scope = scope;
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    { 
      info.AddValue("Scope", _scope);

      base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
  }
```

How I use the exception:

`throw new InvalidCustomCapsBadSumException("Error message is here!, this);`

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionFilterAttribute)); 
}).AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    // ignore circular loops while deserializing
    x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

ExceptionFilterAttribute.cs:

```
public class ExceptionFilterAttribute :  IExceptionFilter
{        
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new
        {
            Exception = context.Exception
        });
    }
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Serializing delegates is not supported on this platform.
   at System.MulticastDelegate.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

Comment: Did serializing a delegate ever actually work correctly?  What JSON was generated?  Anyway, I think you should be able to ignore delegate properties by using `IgnorePropertiesOfTypeContractResolver<System.Delegate>` from [C# Deserialize an object which is derived and has references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42602946)